# rails search form with optional fields

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to make a search form with optional fields so that the user can search by a combination of parameters. I believe the problem is with blank text field values are being passed, but regardless, my searches are not working.

i define scope in app/models/guideline.rb:

```
scope :investor, -> (investor) { where investor: investor }
scope :program, -> (program_code) { where program_code: program_code }
scope :client, -> (client_ID) { where client_ID: client_ID }
```

in the controller, i redefine @guidelines according to form input:

```
def index
  @guidelines = Guideline
  @guidelines = Guideline.program(params[:program_code]) if params[:program_code]
  @guidelines = Guideline.investor(params[:investor]) if params[:investor]
  @guidelines = Guideline.all
end
```

and in the view, I have this simple search form:

```
<%= form_tag guidelines_path, :method => 'get' do %>
  <p>
    <%= text_field_tag :investor, params[:investor], :placeholder => "Enter Investor" %>
    <%= text_field_tag :client_ID, params[:client_ID], :placeholder => "Enter Client"%>
    <%= text_field_tag :program_code, params[:program_code], :placeholder => "Enter Program:" %>
    <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

Eventually I'll want to search on combinations of the form inputs, but I can't even get the simple searches to work. I'd appreciate any help you guys can give me. Thanks!!

Comment: You don't say what's "not working." Can you provide an example? Perhaps show the SQL that's being generated? If you the blank fields are causing problems, as you suggest try using the [`#blank?` method](http://apidock.com/rails/Object/blank%3F): `unless params[:program_code].blank?`

Comment: @jwadsack its obvious by reading his code: ` @guidelines = Guideline.all` overwrite the previous statements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

```
def index
  # All records by default
  @guidelines = Guideline.where(1)
  # Add `program` scope if a value is given
  @guidelines = @guidelines.program(params[:program_code]) unless params[:program_code].blank?
  # Add `investor` scope if a value is given
  @guidelines = @guidelines.investor(params[:investor]) unless params[:investor].blank?
end
```

Note that each scope uses a `unless something.blank?` condition, which excludes the case when the parameter is an empty string

Comment: Thank you! missed reading about the unless condition when reading through documentation.